# Cannot change legend title ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

```
library(ggplot2)

spec_pro <- ggplot(data = cwk_data, aes(x = Age, y = Perf1, colour = BMI_binom)) 
  spec_pro + geom_point() + theme_bw() + ylab("Supervisor Performance Rating") 
  spec_pro + guides(fill=guide_legend("BMI"))
```

Everything works until changing the title of the legend. Then all of the plots and legend disappear entirely.. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look at `?labs`

Comment: Note you set the name of the aesthetic, not the legend: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + labs(colour = 'Cylinders')`

Comment: thanks a lot @user127649, it was solved using `labs(colour='title')`